# Can you use a mongodb table name in variable in a nodejs controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Lets say I got a mongodb table named "bookings", and another named "users" etc etc..

Would it be possible to call a function using a variable/parm as the table name?
Like this:

```
let myData = getRecord("bookings", "ABCDE")
let myData = getRecord("users", "Torben")
```

Here is my suggestion to the code.

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');

var getRecord = (tableName, recordID) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tableName.findOne (
        { "_id":  recordID }
    ,function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return reject(new Error('getRecord ERROR : ' + err));
        }
        if (!data) {
            return reject(new Error('Record Not Found!'));
        }
        return resolve(data);
    })
})};

let myData = getRecord("bookings", "ABCDE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite like that. But you can assign the schemas you create to properties of an object, then use the variable name to look up those properties. So for instance:

```
tables = {
    bookings: new Schema({ ... }),
    users: new Schema({ ... })
};
```

Then in your function, you'd just do:

```
 tables[tableName].findOne(...)
```

Comment: No problem. Note that if you don't need to dynamically generate or manipulate those names, it's better to use @Dimitri L.'s approach. It's always better to pass variable references instead of strings when you can.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you define schemas in mongoose, so you probably defined it somewhere like that:

```
var Bookings = mongoose.model('Bookings', bookingSchema);
```

Now you can just call your code with The class as parameter instead of a string:

```
let myData = getRecord(Bookings, "ABCDE")
```

And you `getRecord` function should work with your code.

Why is it better to use variables/classes instead of strings?
When using the variables directly your IDE will display an error if you make a mistake in the variable name, that wont happen if you just pass a string and make a typo there.

Comment: While this works, there are other reasons the OP might want to use strings, such as being able to dynamically generate the table names for selection. In those cases, simply passing a hardcoded variable reference like this won't work.